# How to make sure 'NA' is "not" the last factor level?

Tags: r, na

The documentation for the factor function states that:

> The codes of a factor may contain NA. For a numeric x, set exclude =
>   NULL to make NA an extra level (prints as ); **by default, this is
>   the last level.**

I do not want this.

My current data looks like this:

[image]

I want my factor levels to be sorted according to in-group size, and that includes my observations with NA values. Is there any way of doing this?

So far I have tried renaming my NA values so something else (using ifelse() and is.na()) the exclude=NULL options in the factor function) and the addNA function.

My current code (I create a sorted table then sort the factor levels based on that):

```
vettig_tabell<-table(fulldata$gymnasiegrov,fulldata$totstatus_tri, exclude=NULL)
vettig_tabell<-as.data.frame(vettig_tabell)
vettig_tabell<-spread(vettig_tabell, Var2, Freq)
vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%mutate(ongoing=`pågående studier`/(`pågående studier` + `tidigt avbrott eller återbud` + `troligt avbrott`))

#sorting by relative frequency#

vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%arrange(ongoing)

#Trying to use order of programmes sorted on relative frequency as factor levels#

fulldata$gymnasiegrov<-factor(fulldata$gymnasiegrov, , exclude=NULL levels=vettig_tabell$Var1, ordered=TRUE)

fulldata %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    group_by(gymnasiegrov, totstatus_tri) %>% 
    summarise(antal = n()) %>% 
    mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal))%>% 
    ggplot(.) + 
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)
```

Excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(gymnasiegrov = c("Hotell- och Restaurang", NA, 
"specialutformat program", "komvux", NA, "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "komvux", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
NA, "specialutformat program", "estetiska programmet", "medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
"specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", "komvux", 
"estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "specialutformat program", 
"friskoleprogram", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"teknikprogrammet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"komvux", "specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "komvux", 
"Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "friskoleprogram", "specialutformat program", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "specialutformat program", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "komvux", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "estetiska programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "estetiska programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), totstatus_tri = c("troligt avbrott", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -162L))

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6emH.png
```

Comment: I can dput an excerpt with the two relevant variables :)

Comment: If it helps I can share the unaltered data from before I apply the factor function and try to sort it.

Comment: I think you should. Because the NAs in the fulldata now, they might have come from your factoring

Comment: Yeah, come to think of it I can't see a reason for "not" doing that. I will replace the dput momentarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a easy solution is to replace the NA in fulldata at the start. I use "Missing" in my example. Since it was a factor to start with, you need to convert it to character then use replace_NA

```
fulldata <- fulldata %>% mutate(gymnasiegrov=replace_na(as.character(gymnasiegrov),"Missing"))
```

Then you do the tabulation..

```
    vettig_tabell<-table(fulldata$gymnasiegrov,fulldata$totstatus_tri, exclude=NULL)
    vettig_tabell<-as.data.frame(vettig_tabell)
    vettig_tabell<-spread(vettig_tabell, Var2, Freq)
    vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%mutate(ongoing=`pågående studier`/(`pågående studier` + `tidigt avbrott eller återbud` + `troligt avbrott`))

#sorting by relative frequency#

vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%arrange(ongoing)
```

## Trying to use order of programmes sorted on relative frequency as factor levels

Then you factor gymnasiegrov again

```
fulldata$gymnasiegrov<-factor(fulldata$gymnasiegrov,levels=vettig_tabell$Var1, ordered=TRUE)
```

And plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 

I previously tried something similar and wrote test$gymnasiegrov<-ifelse(is.na(test$gymnasiegrov),"oklart", as.character(test$gymnasiegrov)). Do you have any idea why your version worked and mine didn't?

Comment: You did not convert the column to character i guess? If you try to introduce a new string into a factor, it becomes NA again :)

Comment: Oh yes, and another thing, you cannot use ifelse like that. It should be test$gymnasiegrov[is.na(test$gymnasiegrov)] <- "oklart". Ifelse returns binary value, meaing "oklart" or "somethingelse" if not NA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this :

```
library(tidyverse)

fulldata %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(gymnasiegrov, totstatus_tri) %>% 
  summarise(antal = n()) %>% 
  mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  replace_na(list(gymnasiegrov = 'NA')) %>%
  arrange(desc(andel)) %>%
  mutate(gymnasiegrov = factor(gymnasiegrov, levels = unique(gymnasiegrov))) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)
```

[image]